# Excel use mouse to jump to beginning of range (opposite of double-clicking cell border to jump to end)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, shortcuts

In Excel when you double-click the border between cells you jump to the end of the range (equivalent to Ctrl+DownArrow or Ctrl+RightArrow).  Is there a way to click somehow to jump to the beginning of the range?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can do this by double-clicking as well.

The sure fire way to do it is to double-click on the top or left of the currently-selected cell.